# Jquery selectize how to set row color by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

it is possible to set different row color for each value in jquery selectize plugin?

i want set row color if ID = 1 to green & if ID = 0 to red

my selectized field:

```
var $select = $('#create_site').selectize({
    preload: true,
    maxItems: 1,
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'title',
    searchField: 'title',
    options: [],
    render: {
        option: function (item, escape) {
            return '<div>' + escape(item.title) + '</div>';
        }
    },
    load: function (query, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://' + $(location).attr('hostname') + '/api/site',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (res) {
                callback(res);
                var $select = $("#selectedsite_create").selectize();
                $select[0].selectize.setValue('11');
                console.log('Success API Sites');
            },
            error: function () {
                callback();
                console.log('Error API Sites');
            }
        });
    },
    onChange: function(value) {
        if (!value.length) return;
        console.log(value);
    },
    create: false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soooooo simple :)
in render just...

```
render: {
        option: function (item, escape) {
            if(item.Online == 1){
                return '<div style="background-color: #c6c6c6">' + escape(item.title) + '</div>';
            }else{
                return '<div>' + escape(item.title) + '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
```